# Accessing other class's properties through paremeterized constructors in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working to generate HTML Table Rows in a TagHelper class to be added to a DataTables table that displays a few buttons in a hidden child row (shown on clicking a given row).  For one of these buttons, I need the value from a property within a different class (corresponding to a value in a separate database table).  I'm not sure how to go about referencing the other class so that it has the correct value for the given survey.  The class layout is something like this:

Relevant Snippet from the TagHelper class I'm working in:

```
public IEnumerable<Survey> listSurv { get; set; }

foreach(Survey surv in listSurv) {
    //Row Construction Happening Before the Button

    //I need to reference the Report class here to get the ReportID (Id in the Report class).
    //Currently, I have this, but it always returns 0
    Report r = new Report();
    innerData.InnerHtml.Append(r.Id.ToString()); //innerData is a TagBuilder element that's previously constructed

}
```

The Report Class:

```
public class Report()
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Survey Survey {get; set;}
    public string DLLink {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date_Uploaded {get; set;}
}
```

Is there some way I can Instantiate the Report class within the TagHelper class in a way that lets me access the Id corresponding with that particular survey?  My initial thought was a paremeterized constructor, but I'm not sure how to go about Implementing that in this particular case.  I'm more of a PHP Developer, so I'm not as familiar with how this would work in a ASP.NET setting.

Comment: "access the Id corresponding with that particular survey" -- So the `Survey` class itself has it's own Id, and this Id is the same as the `Report` classes Id?

Comment: What is the relationship between `Survey` and `Report`? Show us more of your `TagHelper` snippet -- Is that in a method, constructor, where? Possibly also show us your `Survey` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need a link back from `Survey` to `Report`. Without `Survey` code, that one is hard to tell. What you can do is save the report as a reference in the survey, and call that from your code.
What you did now is creating a new `Report`, such that is has always a default id of zero.

So create a report reference in survey:

```
public class Survey {
    public Report Report { get; set; }
}
```

Link the survey instance with a reference to the report instance:

```
var report = GetReport();
var survey = GetSurvey();
survey.Report = report;
```

Now you can retrieve report data from the report property:

```
foreach(Survey survey in listSurv) {
    innerData.InnerHtml.Append(survey.Report.Id.ToString());
}
```